# how to concatenate many files into one matrix for plotting

Tags: matlab, octave

I need to concatenate multiple files' data into one matrix.
So far, the way that I have been testing loading my data is something akin to the following:

```
fid = fopen('data01.txt', 'r');
raw = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f %f %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
m = cellfun(@double, raw, 'UniformOutput', false);
value_of_interest = m{:,10}
```

...But the data set that I have on disk is many files and all exist within a single directory.  I'd prefer to refer to a specific path for this directory, rather than placing my script there.  How can I modify my script so that it loads all data for all of the files in said folder?

So far I have this:

```
dirname = uigetdir;
files = dir(dirname);
fileIndex = find(~[files.isdir]);

for i = 1:length(fileIndex)
    fileName = files(fileIndex(i)).name;
    fid = fopen(fileName, 'r');
    raw = textscan(fid, '%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%f %f %f %f %d', 'delimiter', ',');
    time = [m{:,4}, m{:,5}, m{:,6}];  %needs to contain a float
    converted_time = ((m{:,4} *  3600.0) + (m{:,5} * 60.0) + m{:,6}); %hh:mm:ss -> seconds
    values = power(m{:,10}, 2); 
    values(values <= thresh) = 0;
    % need to concat into the var 'values' here... also need to accumulate the time variable
end 

plot(converted_time, values);
```

...But I need to put the two together.

EDIT: I should mention that I may run out of memory, which is explained later in comments below to my chosen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have another look at how you are defining the `fileName` of the file to be opened. Instead, you should try  `fileName = [dirname, '\', files(fileIndex(i)).name];`, since the `name` field of `files` will not contain the full path. This will solve your problem of referencing a list of files that are not in your current path.

Now, to avoid remembering all the data from all those files, we can do this job per file *inside the loop*:

```
...
    plot(converted_time, values);
    hold('on');
end
```

The short command `hold('on');`, often written simply `hold on;` modifies the plot axes such that subsequent data can be plotted without erasing any previous lines.

Comment: If I am going to run out of memory, this will not work.  I suppose I could write the resulting plot data into a single file somehow?  FWIW, I have 365 text files that are each 20mb.

Comment: If I somehow run out of memory in the propagation of the plot, is there a way to cache it onto disk?

Comment: Not really. But you can try and plot less data points, e.g. by binning, averaging, or subsampling, depending on your data. If you run out of memory, there is no way to see every data point in your plot.

Comment: It looks like I could use something like print() to write plots to disk if I needed to, then tile them together later... 'http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html'

Comment: Interesting, you could do this roughly every 50 files, by testing `if mod(i, 50) == 0`, then use `print`, but also don't forget to use `clf` in order to clear the figure for the next batch of 50. You won't have to reassemble many images then. Good luck and thanks for the hint.